# Match strings surrounding another string

Tags: vim, match

In vim, I am trying to match two strings (up to whitespace) **only if** they have another specified string in between.

Example: Assume some function calls

```
call someFunction(foo, bar)
call anotherFunction(foo)
call thirdFunction(foo, bar)
```

Now if we specify the string foo, bar, i want it to look like this (things inside <> shall be matched)

```
call <someFunction(>foo, bar<)>
call anotherFunction(foo)
call <thirdFunction(>foo, bar<)>
```

An easier example would be to match a string surrounded by something specific. E.g. in `something foo, bar something (foo, bar)` only match the second occurrence of foo, bar, **but not the brackets**. From there on i could probably work it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this matching in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lookaround`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve your goal:

```
(\@<=[^()]*)\@=
```

It can be rewritten as:

```
(\zs[^()]*\ze)
```

They'll match text inside the `(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

First, you cannot match multiple things at the same time in Vim. There's only one (continuous) selection, one text object, etc. What is possible is to capture multiple substrings with a regular expression, and then rearrange those, with the `:substitute` command. Here is one that works for your example:

```
:%s/\(\<\w\+\>(\)foo, bar\()\)/function is \1\2/
```

The `\(...\)` is a *capture group*, and the matched text is inserted via the `\1` etc. in the replacement part. Read `:help :substitute` for details.